# Model averaging for negative gradient boosting?

Tags: cross-validation, boosting

I'm using negative gradient boosting for Cox regression. After finding out the optimum lambda value by evaluating the empirical risk of 10-fold cross validation, I want to determine the final model for prediction.

However, there seems to be two ways to do that:

First, I can average all the coefficients at the optimum lambda from all ten cross-validations.

Second, I can boost one more time with all the data using the optimum lambda.

Since these two methods all give me good results, which one should I use?
Or which one is more accurate theoretically?

Comment: What are good results in your case? How do you measure goodness of fit?

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr**: I recommend not boosting one more time.

**Details:**
We use the train/test split against data, and train only using train, to determine which parameter values give best performance.  When we have determined that estimate performance and those parameter values it is best to stay with them, or be very careful to stay close to them.  Moving too far outside means the estimated performance gets trashed, and there is no way of knowing if there is overfitting or other pathologies.

With the set parameter values, train against all the data, but don't move those values around.